# Session cookie is not set in browser

Tags: heroku, cross-domain, session-cookies, next.js, apollo-client

I have frontend client running on custom Next.js server that is fetching data with apollo client.
My backend is graphql-yoga with prisma utilizing express-session.

I have problem with picking correct CORS settings for my client and backend so cookie would be properly set in the browser, especially on heroku.

Currently I am sending graphql request from client with apollo-client having option
`credentials: "include"` but also have tried `"same-origin"` with no better result.

I can see cookie client in response from my backend in `Set-Cookie` header, and in devTools/application/cookies. But this cookie is transparent to browser and is lost on refresh.

With this said I also tried to implement some afterware to `apollo client` as `apolloLink` that would intercept cookie from `response.headers` but it is empty.

So far now I'm thinking about pursuing those two paths of resolving the issue.

(I'm only implementing CORS because browser prevents fetching data without it.)

*CLIENT*

ApolloClient config for client-side:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  credentials: "include",
  uri: BACKEND_ENDPOINT,
});
```

Client CORS usage and config:

```
 app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
      const server = express()
        .use(cors(corsOptions))
        .options("*", cors(corsOptions))
        .set("trust proxy", 1);

...here goes rest of implementation
```

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [process.env.BACKEND_ENDPOINT, process.env.HEROKU_CORS_URL],
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "X-Forwarded-Proto", "Cookie", "Set-Cookie", '*'],
  methods: "GET,POST",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
```

My atempt to get headers from response in apolloClient(but headers are empty and data is not fetched afterwards):

```
const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
   return forward(operation).map(response => {
     const context = operation.getContext();

     const {response: {headers}} = context;
     if (headers) {
       const cookie = response.headers.get("set-cookie");
       if (cookie) {
         //set cookie here
       }
     }
     return response;
   });

 });
```

*BACKEND*

CORS implementaion (remeber that is gql-yoga so I need first to expose express from it)

```
server.express
  .use(cors(corsOptions))
  .options("*", cors())
  .set("trust proxy", 1);

...here goes rest of implementation
```

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: [process.env.CLIENT_URL_DEV, process.env.CLIENT_URL_PROD, process.env.HEROKU_CORS_URL],
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "X-Forwarded-Proto", "Cookie", "Set-Cookie"],
  exposedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "X-Requested-With", "X-Forwarded-Proto", "Cookie", "Set-Cookie"],
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,OPTIONS",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
```

Session settings, store is `connect-redis`

```
server.express
  .use(
    session({
      store: store,
      genid: () => uuidv4(v4options),
      name: process.env.SESSION_NAME,
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: true,
      rolling: true,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      sameSite: false,
      proxy: STAGE,
      unset: "destroy",
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "/",
        secure: STAGE,
        maxAge: STAGE ? TTL_PROD : TTL_DEV
      }
    })
  )
```

I am expecting session cookie to be set on the client after authentication.

Actual result:
Cookie is visible only in Set-Cookie response header but is transparent to browser and not persistent nor set (lost on refresh or page change). Funny enough I can still make authenticated requests for data.

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: sadly, no - we switched from next.js to cra for this silly reason

Comment: I managed to solve it by using custom domains on frontend and backend in heroku

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a CORS issue, it looks like a third-party cookie problem.

Behaviour could be different across browsers so I recommend testing several ones. Firefox (as of version 77) seems to be less restrictive. In Chrome (as of version 83) there is an indicator on the far right of the URL bar when a third party cookie has been blocked. You can confirm whether third party cookies is the cause of the problem by creating an exception for the current website.

Assuming your current setup is as follows:

```
frontend.com
backend.herokuapp.com
```

Using a custom domain for your backend that is a subdomain of your frontend would solve your problem:

```
frontend.com
api.frontend.com
```

The following setup wouldn't work because `herokuapp.com` is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List:

```
frontend.herokuapp.com
backend.herokuapp.com
```

[More details on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com).